# Acceleration 4-vector in Schwarzschild metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, acceleration

I am working on [A note of a paradoxical property of the Schwarzschild solution](http://www.actaphys.uj.edu.pl/fulltext?series=Reg&vol=5&page=327) by Abramowicz M. A. and Lasota J-P

It is a note on surprising cases in the context of the standard Schwarzschild solution. The authors show that for any location inside $\frac 3 2 R_s$, centrifugal force acts toward the inside.

> Let's consider a family $F(r_0)$ or observers ( in general non
>   inertial ) moving on circular trajectories around the centre of the
>   Schwartzschild field source at a given distance $r_0$ and with
>   constant angular velocities $\Omega$. ( The observers with
>   $r_0^2\Omega^2 \geq 1- \frac {2M} {r_0}$ are unphysical because they move
>   faster than light.) Those, for which $\Omega = 0$ are called static
>   observers.
>
> Now let us ask the following question. Is it possible for all
>   observers of the family $F(r_0)$ to have equal accelerations?
>
> Newtonian intuition prompts the answer: No! However, the correct
>   answer is: Yes, it is possible at $r_0 = 3 M$. This answer follows
>   directly from the fact that  at $r_0 = 3M$
>
> $$a_k = u^i \nabla_iu_k = ( 0, \frac 1 {3M},0,0) ; i,k = 0,1,2,3\tag{1}$$

I don't know how to solve this equation. Could you help me please?

Comment: This question introduced an interesting topic, often ignored. MD. you must start with the S. equation, develop a little and come back to edit the question. Note : the notations of original document ( 1973 ) are not well detailed while it is cited in many publications.